# Replace PLC with Wifi AP or extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am currently looking for a way to replace a part of my wired (Ethernet) local network with a Wifi AP/extender because I have some performance (download speed from Internet) issues.

Here is my current local network layout.
[image: Here is my current local network layout.]

The main issue is that devices connected on the switch (e.g. the PC, bottom left) have reduced download speed compared to devices directly connected on the router (even on 2.4Ghz Wifi). I do think the PLC or the surge protector are responsible. I also have some sync issues with the PLC, so I'd like to get rid of them and replace them by a Wifi AP or extender, so the network would look like

[image: that.]

The main question is: should I use a Wifi extender or a Wifi AP ? Also, is this a good idea or should I expect this whole setup to have some drawbacks (other than the usual Ethernet vs. Wifi debate) ?

Things to consider:

- I can't just connect my switch to the router with an Ethernet cable (distance and walls)
- The router has 5Ghz Wifi, so the AP/extender should have it too
- Wifi range (between router and AP/extender) is not an issue
- I do wish to keep the switch and keep the PC and the NAS wired

**EDIT**: small mistake in the first image: the link between the two PLC is actually a powerline, not an Ethernet cable.

Comment: What is PLC even supposed to mean?

Comment: That: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication#Home_networking_(LAN) ; maybe it has also another name ? (I'm french, maybe there's a translation I'm not aware of)

Comment: I had a similar setup to you a few years ago, and replaced it with two Wireless AP, which definitely improved my speeds to the NAS + PC. When I did this, this was before Eero, or Google WIFI, so it was a ad-hoc wireless bridge but the connection between the two AP is around 700Mbps.

Comment: Well, PLC is generally a Programmable Logic Controller. ;) Just don’t use acronyms unless necessary. // Are you sure the wireless link lives up to your expectations? Take a laptop to the planned location and test it. // Also, did you install the Powerline devices correctly? Plugged directly into the wall? Are there any peculiar devices on the same fuse?

Comment: I still have to make more serious testing but download speed in Wifi with my laptop definitely seems better than with my desktop. As for the powerline devices, they are set up correctly, I have used this kind of devices for years and know how to get the best of them. I'd be tempted to just change them (they are a few years old and may just be malfunctioning) but then again, if I have to invest some money in the problem, I'd like to be sure to end up with something better.